# is using shared libraries is not always better than using a static libraries?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dll, dynamic-linking

lets say we have mutiple .c files as `a.c`, `b.c`, `c.c`, `d.c` ...etc, then we make a share library `sharedlib.so` based on those files and the `main.c` only use a function let's `functionb()` in `b.c`.

as my understand of share libraries, each share library has one `.text` section and this `.text` section contains all the functions' instructions in its member file  `a.c`, `b.c`, `c.c`, `d.c` ...etc. So even `main.c` only use one function, the shared library will be loaded into the memory and therefore the whole `.text` section is in memory, and  `.text` section of `sharedlib.so` contains a lot of functions that `main.c` doesn't use.

Is my above understanding correct? (I understand the benifits of using a shared library as only one copy is in memory compared to static libraries. so generally speaking, it is better to use shared libraries) just want to double check that using shared libraries does result in copying unnesessary things into memory.

Comment: The whole of the shared library is loaded regardless of how much of it you use.  Usage depends on whether you are in full control of the shared library.  If you are expecting a particular version and a different version is loaded, it may or may not work.  Sometimes, because the calls are missing or because the parameters are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but... if *your* app is the *only* one on the system using that library you should use static library whatsoever.

The shared libraries *save* memory because they are *shared*; it is possible to organize them so that for each shared library on a big server, only *one* copy exists in ram even though 10 different exes for 100 different users are using it. This is not possible static libraries; if you have 10 different exes using the same library then you might have 10 copies in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You'd prefer to use shared libraries to save up memory on your system.
Static libraries are efficient but very costly on you memory.

Using shared libraries will lower significantly the size of your binaries.
More over you'd have a single copy of your shared library instead of one copy for each static link.

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

gcc will indeed concatenate the text sections from multiple object files into a single text section, and the loader will indeed load the entire text section "into memory". However, you shouldn't assume that "memory" in this case refers to physical memory. The whole library will occupy a portion of the virtual address space of a process that links it, but it need not occupy the same amount of physical memory. Ideally, only specific pages of virtual memory corresponding to functions that are used will be mapped to physical memory.

In addition, to some extent physical memory pages can be mapped into the virtual address space of multiple processes, if these processes use the same library. However, there are many complications involving this kind of page sharing.

Nevertheless the problem is a real one, if only to the extent that a bloated shared object can lead to a lot of memory paging. There are many tricks associated with optimizing the memory behaviour of shared objects, such as placing functions that call one another close together in source code, so they are likely to end up in the same memory page.